# How to filter items while doing async calls on user input?

Tags: ajax, angular, rxjs, observable, debouncing

I have an input field in my HTML, like this:

```
<input (keyup)="userInput($event)" type="text">
```

Inside my component, I am taking the user input and checking with backend if it is a valid input or not. Before I make this call, I do a simple empty check on the variable.

```
userInput(e: any): void {
    this.userInputText = e.target.value;
    if (this.userInputText === '') { //Empty string check
        this.validInput = false;
    } else { // Check backend for availability
        this.userInput.next(this.userInputText);
    }
}
```

My userInput Subject is

```
this.userInput
.debounceTime(1000)
.switchMap((val) => {
    return this.checkValidity(val); //service call
}).subscribe((res) => {
    this.validInput = res.status;
}, (err) => {
    ResponseHandler(err);
});
```

The **problem** is the empty check I do.

Imagine user input two characters 'of' and I show it as valid (by making a call).

If the user hits backspace (input is now 'o'), wait for a second (causing a call for text 'o') and hit backspace to delete 'o' (resulting in empty user input) my status shows invalid cause the input field is empty.

Then the ajax call response comes back (for text 'o', which is valid) and I show valid. So I end up showing valid for an empty string.
How do I resolve this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put the empty check into the observable stream and not have the work around you have...

```
this.userInput
 .debounceTime(1000)
 .distinctUntilChanged()
 .switchMap((val) => (val) ? this.checkValidity(val) : Observable.of({status: false}))
 .subscribe((res) => {
       this.validInput = res.status;
 }, (err) => {
    ResponseHandler(err);
 });
```

and just tie the key up straight to the user input subject

This solves your timing problem because of how the switchmap operator works.

switchMap takes a value and maps it into a subscription to a new inner observable, but more importantly, it cancels and ignores values from previously subscribed inner observables. This is why with switch map, if the user enters w then o, it doesn't matter that switch map received "w" then "wo", since as soon as it gets the second value, whether the async "w" query has returned or not, or if (somehow) the "wo" query beats the "w" query back, as it will ignore or cancel the "w" query as soon as it receives the new "wo" value, the same is true with the blank value, as if the user then erased their input before the previous queries finished, switchMap would ignore or cancel all previous unfinished queries, and it will only return the mocked invalid query result from the latest inner observable. this is why it's called switchMap, it switches to and maps into the latest inner observable.

if you were to use an operator like mergeMap, which is a different higher order operator that also maps into a new inner observable, this process wouldn't work, because mergeMap doesn't switch, it returns all values from inner observables in the order they arrive, regardless of what new values come in.  Sometimes this is what you're after, not in this case though.

Bonus tip, the distinctUntilChanged() operator I added makes this process a little more efficient, as if the user were to do something like enter w, (execute a query) then enter o and immediately remove the o within the debounce timeframe, it will ignore the next "w" sent through since it only passes new values to switchmap and ignores sequential duplicate values, so you won't have to requery for "w"

Comment: Thanks! What I'll be doing here is mocking an observable of invalid input response. I will give this a try but I am not sure how this will resolve the timing issue.

`--> User input: o (call made)
--> User hits backspace. Mock observable returned, marking invalid input
--> Call finishes, response is valid`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, you're missing the function of the switch map operator which switches to the latest subscription and cancels previous subscriptions. This kind of thing is the quintessential switchmap case. This kind of problem was extremely troublesome prior to switch map for this reason.

Comment: This wasn't working before because you were doing the synchronous validation outside of the observable stream, that's no longer the case so it will always be showing the result for the latest user input.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but applause  for the explanation. It's not code that I copy pasted and it worked. It's code that I do understand. Thanks for the writeup.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're performing asynchronous actions and expecting a synchronous result. You need to find a way to resolve the asynchronous nature of your program.

A few possible solutions that come to mind immediately:

1) You could disable input while the server-side validation is occurring.

2) Since solution 1 isn't quite as fluid, you might consider setting a flag just before sending your request to the server (e.g. `input_changed_during request = false;`, modifying its value when the input is changed (e.g. `input_changed_during_request = true;`, and then checking it upon receiving the status from the server and discarding your validating results if the input was modified during the validation process.

3) You could do the debounced input validation client-side and then revalidate the input when it gets to the server on submit.